# Using dictionaries in Mako templates

Tags: python, mako

Instead of passing variables to a template like so:

```
template.render(var1='hello', var2='world')
```

How can I pass a dictionary to the template and have it render in the same manner

```
vars = {'var1': 'hello', 'var2': 'world'}
```

so in the template I can display the variables as normal:

```
${var1} ${var2}
```

I don't want any extra code in the template so I was thinking of using the Context object somehow, but I have hit a brick wall. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know mako, but to use a dict as [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (or kwargs), you have to prepend two `*`:

```
template.render(**vars)
```